# Does one Container runs one chaincode in Hyperledger? When to stop the chaincode?

Tags: hyperledger

I have some questions about the process of the hyperledger.
When to start a container? only one chaincode will setup on a container and holding for transactions? Or many chaincode will be setted? 
The container will run all the time or have some regulations tell when to stop the chaincode/container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“Hyperledger” is a protocol specification under Linux Foundation guidance. In [github](https://github.com/hyperledger/) account there are 2 implementations:

- Fabric (IBM)
- Sawtooth Lake (Intel)

Answer to your questions depends on implementation you are interested in.

In Fabric each chaincode is deployed in separate Docker container. When Validation Peer receives “deploy” request, it creates docker image and immediately starts container. As soon as container started, VP will execute chaincode’s  “Init” method. From this moment chaincode is ready to serve incoming requests.

Fabric project is in development, in current version containers are run all the time. This behaviour can be changed later. 
If you will try to stop container manually, it will be restarted again at the moment when VP receives “Invoke” or “Query” request for this specific chaincode.

Comment: Really appreciate!!! Could you give me some advice about how to design the Blockchain? I have two methods of committing a block to blockchain. One of them is one chaincode's transactions commit to a blockchain this gets more efficient with searching, but this will get so many blockchains. The other is different chaincode's transactions commit to one blockchain it will waste of time for searching, and if I update a chaincode the old chaincode still on the chain... Which looks better or some other methods?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: I mean in Fabric ledger contains many blockchain, blockchain have many blocks. How to commit transactions to block is the better way? Same chaincode's transactions commit to the same blockchain or all chaincode's transactions commit to one blockchain? Further more, do you know how many transactions, which get consensus, are the critical point commit to ledger using consensus.Executor.CommitTxBatch? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Fabric ledger can be build on top of multiple peers, nevertheless all of them have the same copy of blockchain. There is just one blockchain in a ledger. 
We have very little control on how transactions are committed to the ledger. 
1. If you use NOOPS consensus - every transaction will be committed in separate block. 
2. PBFT consensus works in batch mode only. You can specify batch size, timeouts, several more settings in config file.

Comment: Really appreciate!!

Comment: @SergeyBalashevich  when a chaincode invoke another chaincode, are they communicate between container?

Comment: @alchemist In order to invoke another chaincode, first smart contract will send message back to Validation Peer using shim method ‘InvokeChaincode’ . This request will be executed using the same transaction context. Peer will verify if another chaincode is started (or start it if necessary) and then Peer will  1) call another chaincode’s “Invoke” method 2) wait until response is generated 3) forward answer back to first smart contract.